# Impressionist gem returning zero, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, impressionist

Whats wrong with my code?
Here's the index

```
<%= post.impressionist_count(:filter=>:ip_address) %>
```

Here's the controller

```
impressionist actions: [:show], unique: [:session_hash]
  is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :my_column_name, :unique => true
```

Here's the post.rb

```
is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :my_column_name, :unique => true
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough, I didn't.

Comment: @Bengala are you dealing with the same problem?